# Normality Problems

Tags: normalization

I'm doing a regression analysis which involves 4 independent variables (IV). I performed a Shapiro-Wilk test to test the normality of of each of the IVs and it turned out that the the test showed a value less than 0.05 (which means the data is not normally distributed).

So the question is how do i make my data to follow a normal distribution. Because all parametric tests are based on the assumption that the data is normally distributed.

My data set consist of 26 records (n=26). The dependent variable is House Price Index. 
While the IV is Gross Domestic Product, Population, Lending Rates and Gross National Income.

Therefore I'm trying to come up with a regression model with these variables. But im facing the normality problem in the IV and DV data distributions.

Thank you.

Comment: It is *not* true that your data has to be always and exactly normally distributed for parametric tests, see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless and if you really need to transform you data, Box-Cox is the simple and commonly used approach http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box.E2.80.93Cox_transformation But to provide the precise answer you have to tell what is your data and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Tim Thank you Tim. I have added more details to my question.

Comment: With such a small sample the *sample size* should be a greater concern to you than normality.

Comment: @Tim Agreed Tim. I would want to increase the number of records but the available (published) data is only that much.

Comment: Are these cross-sectional data for several countries or time series for one country (or ...). If the first, then it is likely, at a minimum, that you need to transform most predictors, but not because they are non-normal, rather because you would be unlikely to get anything but absurd fits otherwise. The choice of predictors seems fairly strange too, but that is a different problem.

Comment: @NickCox This is for one country...its to study the relation between macroeconomic indicators on housing prices..

Comment: Not my field, but it sounds more like a time series problem then.

Comment: Please explain what *form* of "regression analysis" you are using that requires the IVs to have (approximately) normal distributions.

Comment: @whuber I'm using a linear regression model (at the moment)...I may try out non-linear ones as well.

Comment: That makes no suppositions whatsoever about the distributions of the IVs. That makes your problem disappear.  For more about this issue, please see the results of a [site search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20transformation%20distribution%20independent).